# Gradle 2.3.0-alpha1 doesn't work data binding

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-databinding, parceler

I have a problem after updating to Android Studo 2.3 Canary today.

The build completed with no error but when I run the app, the gradle console keeps showing:

> android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding not found

Here's my `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle 2.3.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.1'
        classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thanks !

---Updated---
I was struggling for few days and I found where problem comes from.
I use Parcels, Retrolamdas in my app, both libraries use 'apt' and that's problem.

**build.gradle (root) bug version :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1'
        classpath "me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3"
        classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (app) bug version **

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

...

dependencies {
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.5'
    apt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5'
}
```

And here is fixed.
**build.gradle (root) fixed version :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (app) fixed version***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.5'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5'
```

---

Conclusion.
I changed retrolamdas repo version and remove plugin: 'android-apt'
.I was found some helpful links if you want looks into details.

https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/201
https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration

Hope it helps :D

Comment: what do you need `dataBinder` for?

Comment: I only follow android data binding guidelines. any problem with dataBinder ?

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#build_environment

Comment: I tried to remove the line classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1' but it still keep show error above

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a problem related to android-apt.

Comment: Maybe. I was struggling on google but there's no luck :(

Comment: had the same issue, it is coming from the new gradle pluging, you need to revert back to - 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'on your main gradle file. But Then you must go back to Android Studio 2.2.2. both did the trick for me

Comment: Agree. I also did that - back to gradle 2.2.2 + Android Studio 2.2.2 and everything works fine. But I really need my project can run on AS 2.3 because Instant run very very slow (4 - 6 minutes) and it was fixed on AS 2.3 :)

Comment: There are already two android issues filed: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227612 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227657. For me it is enough to downgrade the gradle plugin to 2.2.2 for successful builds.

Comment: Yes we can downgrade to gradle 2.2.2 but it's bug and it should be fixed asap

Answer (score 6):

This issue is triggered because we've moved data binding to annotationProcessor configuration (rather than provided).
If you are using android-apt`, they'll conflict, stop using it.
We also had another bug which prevented it from picking other processors. It is already fixed and will be available in the next alpha.

Original bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227612. It also has a work around if you really need to use 2.3 .

Comment: Please share a sample app in the bug report that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 4):

I was using android-apt.  I replaced with annotationProcessor and solve my problem

I have removed

> apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

and changed Dagger library code

> compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
>
> annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
>
> provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

Comment: Do you have any ideas about `androidTestApt` ? after removing the `android-apt` I have an error on build process :(

Answer (score -4):

Temporaral fix that worked for me:
1. Change gradle version to: 
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'`

2. Turn off instant run
3. Wait for an update from Google :)

Comment: it costs me 2 - 3 minutes for each time running the app :)) it's so 'amazing' (crying)